# Why does size of the qr image doesn't gets changed even on using the size property of QRImage widget which comes with the qr_flutter package?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm using the "qr_flutter" package for the generation of the Qr code, Within the qr_flutter package, we do have a widget named `QRImage()` which has certain properties, as per my requirement, I need to change the size of the QR image when ever user opts for the specific size. I tried using the below code to do so, but the actual QR image size doesn't change instead the size extended with blank space at the bottom.

Here is the snippet :

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: RepaintBoundary(
                    key: globalKey,
                    child: Expanded(
                      child: QrImage(
                        //plce where the QR Image will be shown
                        data: qrData,
                        size: 1000.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),]))),
```

Below is the output QR code generated:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-O9cuCkZ6hHNDz6IU_VuaSlzli5riDME/view?usp=sharing

Comment: as I see it in your picture your QR Image actually does stretch  across the screen width? does it not? Do you want to zoom in even more?

Comment: No the width doesnt got stretched only the height got stretched, i actually want to project this image on a projector so that the students in a class of some xyz dimensions can scan it. Do you have any idea regarding till what dimensions can this image be abled to get scanned?